# create transition matrix displaying all states using acast() when data has no information on all states

Tags: r

I would like to create a transition matrix using `acast()` showing transitions in states from one point in time to another. There are 5 possible states (1 to 5), but my data does not hold information on all states:

E.g.

```
possible_states = 1:5

state_1 = c(3:5, 4:5)
state_2 = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
number  = c(2, 1, 3, 5, 6)

df1 = data.frame(state_1,
                 state_2,
                 number)

> df1
  state_1 state_2 number
1       3       3      2
2       4       3      1
3       5       4      3
4       4       4      5
5       5       4      6
```

`df1` is then to be read as follows: from one point in time to another, there were/was

- 2 observations in state = 2 that remained in state = 2 (first row)
- 1 observation in state = 4 that went to state = 3 (second row)
- ...

As you can see, there is no info on certain states. As a result the code below leads to a transition matrix that does not list all possible states:

```
> acast(df1, state_1 ~ state_2, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "number")
  3 4
3 2 0
4 1 5
5 0 9
```

I would like to have the outcome:

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 2 0 0
4 0 0 1 5 0
5 0 0 0 9 0
```

Is there an efficient way to obtain a transition matrix displaying all states (also when there are no observations for those states)?

I can do it by adding the missing states (e.g. see below), but it seems a bitcumbersome:

```
missing_states = unique(c(possible_states[!(possible_states %in% state_1)], possible_states[!(possible_states %in% state_2)]))

df2 = data.frame(state_1 = missing_states,
                 state_2 = missing_states,
                 number = rep(0, length(missing_states)))

df = rbind(df1, df2)

acast(df, state_1 ~ state_2, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "number")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set the variable to a `factor` and set the `levels` argument.

So using `reshape2::acast`, and also setting `drop=FALSE`:

```
acast(df1, factor(state_1, levels=possible_states) ~ 
                              factor(state_2, levels=possible_states),
          fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "number", drop=FALSE)
```

Or using `xtabs` (where default is to keep unused levels):

```
xtabs(data=df1, number ~ factor(state_1, levels=possible_states) + 
                         factor(state_2, levels=possible_states))
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it work with base R

```
with(aggregate(list(number = df1$number), df1[colnames(df1)[1:2]], sum), 
     sapply(1:5, function(x)
         sapply(1:5, function(y)
             max(0, number[state_1 == y & state_2 == x]))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    2    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    1    5    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    9    0
```